# Identify thread of current scope

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How does one determine the thread a given function call is running on?

I want to make sure a method is called on the main thread in order to update some UI elements.

Can I for example do something like this?

```
- (void) myMethod {
    if (<current thread is not main thread>) {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(myMethod) withObject: nil waitUntilDone: NO];
    } else {
        // my code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [NSThread isMainThread].

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSThread/isMainThread

Comment: That works; two caveats.   Sometimes it is more useful to lock to a runloop and not a thread (there is one runloop per thread, so it is synonymous, but sometimes more declarative of intention).   If using the dispatch_* or NSOperation* APIs, the thread may be relatively random.

Comment: Thanks Bill.. I was trying to keep it simple for Errol but you made great points to keep in mind.

Comment: I'll look into the run-loop vs thread business, but essentially I just need to know that my method was performed on the main thread because I'm making UI updates.